# sfdx force:source:push customObject Errors

Tags: salesforcedx

When I run "sfdx force:source:push -u myScratchOrgAlias -x manifest/package.xml I eventually get an error for validation rules, object-meta, page layouts, etc. even though page Layouts and validation rules are not in my package.xml.

I just want to push the custom object and custom fields on the object to the scratch org, but when I include the customObject in the package.xml it tries to push the other child components with it which don't exist. If I had to include everything that was connected to the validation rules on the object then my package would become gigantic. Pleae help!

edit - I added a smaller version of my package.xml that still errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Balance__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Bill_To__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Change_Notes__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Company__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Contact_Email__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Contact__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Customer_PO_No__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Customer__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Customers_Since_Formula_Reference__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Has_Fast_Turns__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Internal_Notes__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Invoiced_Line_Items__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Opportunity__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Order_Acknowledgement_Notes__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Order_Acknowledgement_Sent__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Order_Date__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Process_Update__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Req_Qty_Total__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Sales_Order_Line_Items_Count__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Secondary_Contact_Email__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Secondary_Contact__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Ship_Full__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Shipped_Qty_Total__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Status__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Total_Invoiced_Amount__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Total_Margin__c</members>
        <members>Sales_Order__c.Total_Order_Price__c</members>
        <name>CustomField</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Sales_Order__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <version>48.0</version>
</Package>
```

Comment: please use [edit] and show your `manifest/package.xml`

Comment: Done. Appreciate any guidance. Thank you

Comment: there is no `-x` param for `force:source:push`. [Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_push)

Comment: Sorry, that was actually for the 'sfdx force:source:retrieve' command